# Amadeus API authorization request failing because "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing"

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, axios, access-token, amadeus

I am trying to request an authorization token from Amadeus using axios by following [this documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262). However, I'm quite unexperienced with the axios library and am failing to build the request correctly, because I get this response:

```
code: 38187
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing"
title: "Invalid parameters"
```

The curious thing is that I tried to simulate the same request with curl and it worked, so I'm really puzzled as to where my error is. Below is my curl request

```
curl -v "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token"
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxx"
```

Here is my JavaScript code, please let me know if you are able to notice the difference! Thanks in advance

```
async getAmadeusKey() {
    const response = await axios({
        url: "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },

        data: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,  // of course both these constants are defined outside of this scope
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        }
    });
    console.log(response.data);
}
```

Edit: I had an error with the header, but the response misidentified the error on my request even after applying the fix suggested below. Note that the header should have Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, axios serialises the `data` parameter as JSON. Since you want to send a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, you will have to serialize the `data` parameter in that format instead.

If you're targeting modern browsers only, you can use `URLSearchParams` like so:

```js
const data = new URLSearchParams({
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
})

const response = await axios({
  ... // your code here
  data,
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! It did work, but I also had an issue with the header and only after those two changes it worked.